# codeigniter mysql bitwise operator

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, bitwise-operators

I have a value in my database (int) decimal. I have several constants in my codeigniter application linked to a binary 1 - 2 - 4 - 8 - ... .

I wanted to get all users with a specific binary acces level to be shown.

```
public function query($level = 0)
{
    $data = NULL;

    $this->db->select('user_id, user_email, user_name, user_firstname, user_imageammount, user_auth');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('user_auth' & $level);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $data = $query->result_array();
    }

    return $data;
}
```

When i run the query straight in my phpmyadmin i get the results that i need.

```
SELECT `user_id`, `user_email`, `user_name`, `user_firstname`, `user_imageammount`, `user_auth` FROM `users` WHERE `user_auth` & 1
```

When i run it in codeigniter i get a error.

**Severity: Warning
Message: A non-numeric value encountered**

Any help or advice would be appriciated.

Comment: This is obviously wrong `$this->db->where('user_auth' & $level);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously wrong:

```
$this->db->where('user_auth' & $level);
```

For one thing you don't have the `.` to concatenate the string part to the non-string part.  Even if you had `'user_auth' . & $level`, it would still be wrong as the opperator `&` should be treated as any operater such as `<`,`>`,`<>` or `!=` etc.  In that it too should be a string.  As it stands it's probably a syntax (or similar parse) error, a simple [test](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d460898151dbc1baa1131adefab9d99f8e4401a2) tells me this:

> **Warning**:  A non-numeric value encountered in **[...][...]** on line **5**

So try this instead:

```
 $this->db->where('user_auth & '.(int)$level);
```

A simple example makes this clear:

```
 #this is wrong
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_auth" & 1;

 #this is correct
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_auth & 1";
```

For this guy you can get away with just casting the `level` to an INT, this should sanitize it plenty fine as it's just an integer value.  I have to make sure that it's understood that sanitizing is always important.  Prepared queries are preferred but in cases where it's a simple INT (most likely drawn from class constants) we will be ok with just casting it as anything that is not an INT just becomes `0`, which at worst won't return any results.

The point is, even when using class constants in a query it should be sanitized. Especially if that constant is passed in as a function argument.  This is because the function could be used with 'unclean' data and you have no way to know if it's safe without looking though a lot of code.  If you clean it right by the query you know it's always taken care of, etc.

Enjoy!

Comment: Sure it was a simple typo, you should turn on full error reporting when developing then you would see this as a warning.  Let PHP tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Might be a good idea indeed. I am pretty new with development in php so all advice is welcome.

Btw is the &~ (and not) operator possible in mysql? I seem to be just recieving the & operator.

Comment: @Pieter-JanCasteels `&~` works fine in MySQL (e.g. `SELECT 24&~8` returns 16) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a22c9179b1dfd962601fbf4146e19c5

Comment: Very strange. In my mysql i don't recieve the correct information. With the & operator i recieve the once that countain a 1 and with the &~ i recieve them all ?

https://i.imgur.com/7q6ckuC.jpg